# Write some text to a File - Exception

Tags: java, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I want to write data to a text file. But, in my application, i will want to keep on writing items to the text file (Which means, the text that i want to write, should be appended to the file - and not create a new file every time)

My code, is as follows; But how could i append text the next time i am writing something to the file ?

1.) The problem with the code below is, the first time writes to the file, but when i am trying to write for the 2nd time i get the following exception;

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
```

2.) I want to be able to write to the same file untill the application is closed. Therefore, how can i close the Stream when the application is closed ?

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WriteToFileExample {
    public void writeToFile(String stuff) {
        try {
                File file = new File("../somefile.txt");

            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(),true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(stuff);
            bw.close();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
private File file;
public WriteToFileExample(){
                 file = new File("../somefile.txt");

}


public void writeToFile(String stuff) {
            try {


                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }

                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                bw.write(stuff);
                bw.close();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

EXCEPTION

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.proj.example.Log.WriteToFile(WriteToFileExample.java:3)
```

Which points to `if (!file.exists()) {`.

Comment: So you want me to remove the `file.exists()` check ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never close the FileWriter in your code. And from the documentation for the class:

> Whether or not a file is available or may be created depends upon the
>   underlying platform. Some platforms, in particular, allow a file to be
>   opened for writing by only one FileWriter (or other file-writing
>   object) at a time. In such situations the constructors in this class
>   will fail if the file involved is already open.

Close the file writer before exiting your method, its good practice anyway. And yes, definitely do open the writer in append mode, if you don't want the files contents to be blown away every time you call your method.

Comment: I have updated my code as you suggest but i still end up with and exception. `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Where? On the same code, in a different part of the code? On the first or second iteration? Please edit your question with the exception stacktrace.

Comment: Looks like your `file` is null when your method is called. Since you seem to be creating it in your constructor, you might want to check and verify that you are not setting it null elsewhere. Also, make sure you are using the correct constructor when creating your class.

Comment: Thank you i solved it. But do you know how to append the text in a newline

Comment: Wrap the file writer in a print writer (`final PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);` and use it `pw.println(stuff);`. Don't forget to close it when done - `pw.close()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
```

Use the true argument for the FileWriter constructor.

Comment: i have updated the code, i still get an exception `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Answer (score 2):

You should create your `FileWriter` using [the contructor that takes an extra boolean argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29), that indicates that you want to append.

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Checking the api, says that the FileWriter constructor takes a boolean to flag whether to append or not. That answer your question?

Comment: Answers part 1 of the question

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing this:

`FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());`

do as follow:

`FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(),true);`

As to append on a existing file [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29) needs an extra argument as true here

> FileWriter
>
> ```
> public FileWriter(File file, boolean append) throws IOException
> ```
>
> Constructs a FileWriter object given a File object. If the second argument is true, then bytes will be
> written to the end of the file rather than the beginning.
>
> **Parameters**:
>
> file - a File object to write to
>
> append - if true, then bytes will be
> written to the end of the file rather than the beginning
>
> **Throws:**
> IOException - if the file exists but is a directory rather than a
> regular file, does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be
> opened for any other reason
>
> Since:
> 1.4